# Query Active Directory Organization Units with Microsoft Graph APi

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

How can I query for a tenants Active Directory organization units(OU) that have been synced to Azure using ADDS(Active Directory Domain Services) Sync?

According to: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-create-ou/

```
Warning:
User accounts, groups, service accounts and computer objects that you create under 
custom OUs will not be available in your Azure AD tenant. In other words, these 
objects will not show up using the Azure AD Graph API or in the Azure AD UI. These 
objects will only be available in your Azure AD Domain Services managed domain.
```

So, is this just a flat "not possible"? Or is there another way? Is it possible using a different Microsoft api other than Graph?

Comment: We use Azure AD Connect and are interested in the same thing.

Comment: I spoke with MS support and there really isn't a way to do this. AD and Azure AD don't mirror each other.