# Microsoft Graph API in particular active directory OU

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I can find all users with below graph api URL

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=500

But it give response with all users of the organization, in which it come with certain service account users. We have all user in some particular OU some thing like this

```
DC=domainName,DC=local,OU=domainName-HO
```

So I want to know that is there any way to find users from particular OU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Custom OU considerations and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/create-ou#custom-ou-considerations-and-limitations), user accounts, groups, service accounts, and computer objects that you create under custom OUs aren't available in your Azure AD tenant. They don't show up using the Azure AD Graph API or in the Azure AD UI.

[A similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456756/query-active-directory-organization-units-with-microsoft-graph-api) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Users API can return a property called onPremiseDistinguishedName which will return a string containing the OUs an account is in. However, MS makes a caveat:

"The property is only populated for customers who are synchronizing their on-premises directory to Azure Active Directory via Azure AD Connect". (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0)

So not relevant for all use cases, but has helped me in the past.