# MS Graph - How do I list all users from specific OU under my DC?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

I'm building a Logic App to list all users from MS Graph.
I can get the list of all users by calling MS Graph API using OAuth authentication in my Logic App but I'm struggling to apply a filter in my custom request in MS Graph.

i.e. I have below structure in my OnPremiseAD:

```
OU=Site1,OU=Users,OU=TEST,DC=xyz,DC=com
OU=Site2,OU=Users,OU=TEST,DC=xyz,DC=com
OU=Site3,OU=Users,OU=TEST,DC=xyz,DC=com
OU=Site4,OU=Users,OU=TEST,DC=xyz,DC=com
```

...and I want to list users from OU=Site4 only.

Can someone please help?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter...???
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Custom OU considerations and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/create-ou#custom-ou-considerations-and-limitations)：

- User accounts, groups, service accounts, and computer objects that
  you create under custom OUs aren't available in your Azure AD tenant.

  - These objects don't show up using the **Microsoft Graph API** or in the
    Azure AD UI; they're only available in your managed domain.

So I'm afraid that it's not supported to list the users under an OU via Microsoft Graph API.

See a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645821/microsoft-graph-api-in-particular-active-directory-ou).